# Consume WCF in java application

Tags: wcf

I have a WCF which return a collection of a class. 
When i consume it on .net application generally i make a deep copy of server return collection to local collection.

Now I want to consume it in java application so how it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes using one http binding.

You can also check this: http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop

Comment: thanks, its quite informative, but still unable to figure out how to convert server return collection in java's collection.

Comment: Look on google how to consume a webservice with Java, and setup your WCF service with one http binding, and you will make it.